# What value do I use for the "Server" field when installing DotNetNuke with the Microsoft App Installer?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I created a database called `dnndb` and a user called `dnnusr` in MS SQL 2008 in my website panel.

When I get through the app installer my site passes the permissions check. I get to the stage that requires these fields:

**Server:
Enter the Name or IP Address of the computer where the Database is located. (if using Oracle enter the Data Source (SID**

**Database:
Enter the Database name**

So the database name is `dnndb` but what is the **Server?** The default value is `.\SQLExpress` which can't be right since my db is MS SQL 2008, but what do I change it to?

I know what you are going to say - **"read the documentation!!"**

Well, I did do that, but instructions are for using simple "." for **local install** with SQL Server Express and "otherwise set up your database manually". Well I did set it up manually, but I don't know how to handle this field with my set up MS SQL database.

Any DotNetNuke People around here??

Answer (score 2):

Installer asks for a value to use in the [SqlClient connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)'s `Data Source` attribute.

The value is usually a `<host name>\<instance name>` pair, but it can be more simple or complex depending if the SQL Server is local or remote, if it is a [default instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx) of a named instance, if you are using the default TCP port 1433 or some different port etc.

For a local server and default instance use any of the following:

```
.
(local)
localhost
```

If you do not specify a named instance, MS SQL Standard / Web / Enterprise installer creates a default instance.

However, SQL Server Express installer creates a named instance `SQLExpress` by default. `.\SQLExpress` is a correct Data Source value for this local instance.